# SocketTimeoutException: Connect Timed Out for using RestAssured from TeamCity

Tags: selenium, teamcity, rest-assured

I have tried below :

1. Increased connection time out through code

   RestAssuredConfig newConfig = RestAssured.config() .httpClient(HttpClientConfig.httpClientConfig().setParam(CoreConnectionPNames.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, 12000).setParam(CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT, 12000));
2. Added User-Agent in request header
3. Checked same api call manually from local system and remote agent-
   both gives same result.

But I am getting java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out while it is working from local system and not from Teamcity agent execution

Please help

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that TeamCity has a timeout of its own, which has not been changed through your code. You can change this property by setting an internal property in *Administration > diagnostics > internal properties*.

Here is the property to add:
`teamcity.agentServer.connectionTimeout=12000`

Here is the [documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Configuring+TeamCity+Server+Startup+Properties#ConfiguringTeamCityServerStartupProperties-TeamCityinternalproperties) for TeamCity startup properties.

I also read through this Youtrack [ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-32011) with a similar issue.